# Uncaught TypeError: arrayName.sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, typescript, ecmascript-5

- I am trying to sort the values using the map method.
- but I am getting an error Uncaught TypeError: arrayName.sort is not a function.
- can you tell me how to sort it.
- can you tell me how to solve using the below methods, since I am learning functional programmming

  .map()
  .filter()
  .find()
  .replace()
  .reduce()
  forEach()
- providing my code below.

```or-tag-here
// ARRAY 2
const newieyork = [
  {
    name: 'Michelle',
    age: 19,
    coder:true,
    gender: 'f',
    us: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Sam',
    age: 25,
    coder:false,
    gender: 'm',
    us: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Ivy',
    age: 26,
    coder:true,
    gender: 'f',
    us: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Nick',
    age: 32,
    coder:true,
    gender: 'm',
    us: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jim Beglin',
    age: 65,
    coder:false,
    gender: 'm',
    us: true,
  },
]

// Part 1 - List all users in US in ascending order
newieyork.sort();
//console.log("newieyork.sort();--->", newieyork.sort());
newieyork.map(function(newieyork){
  //console.log("texasss.name--->", newieyork.name);
 let arrayName =[];
arrayName = newieyork.name;
console.log("arrayName--->", arrayName.sort()); 



});
```

Comment: `arrayName = newieyork.name; arrayName.sort()` You can't `sort` a string...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by sorting on the arrayName? Do you want the array sorted by name order? Or are you attempting to print the strings with the letters sorted in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are assigning to a string:

```
let arrayName =[];
arrayName = newieyork.name; // Assigning to a string
```

`sort` is not a method on a string.